# deploying an open source code igniter application

Tags: codeigniter, open-source

If i've built a web app using code igniter, what's the proper way to deploy it? Should my install only include my files, or do I also package all the codeigniter code with it?

I'm just entering into the world of open source so I'm not so sure what protocol is. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question and I've seen it done both ways. There's definitely reasons Not to include the CI files. Like any potential in the future license changes. And it seems like with the projects that are shared by more experienced developers that is how they do it.

Because if you are sharing your project for other CI developers, then the reality is they will not use the copy of CI you include - they will fold your files into their version of CI. So including JUST the files needed for your app - actually makes much it easier. Its certainly what I would prefer. Just keep the standard application folder structure: config controllers models etc. but only include the folders that you have files for. And make it clear what version of CI you have tested it on. If you can say it will work on the release version (not the beta) then people on PHP 5.2 will know they can use it.

Comment: @mogsdad - just curious - why did you edit this random post from over two years ago? p.s. I promise to try and Capitilize more in the answers.

Comment: Hi! Not random, part of a [general clean up](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22thanks%20in%20advance%22%20is%3aanswer). Many answers with "thanks in advance" in them aren't actually answers, so we're flagging those for deletion while fixing the rest, working backwards in time. There had been something like 400 in that search just a week ago. FWIW, I have a [Magic™ Editor](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/UserScripts#magic-editor) that makes many of the most common corrections in one click.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you need to include all the CodeIgniter files, or else how would it run?

Most people tend to rename the application and system files and place them outside of the web root for security reasons. "After moving them, open your main index.php file and set the `$system_folder` and `$application_folder` variables, preferably with a full path, e.g. '/www/MyUser/system'".